# Getting Error to get device token in ionic 1 with angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want to send notification using ionic 1 with angularJs. I tried to get Device token using
**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm** plugin . Please check why am not getting device token

```
  angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova','chart.js'])

 .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
       $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 FCMPlugin.getToken(
        function(token1){
        $rootScope.fcmToken=token1;
       alert(token1);
     },
    function(err){
    alert(err.error);
    console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
   }
   );
    FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function(rtoken){
         alert("re_token" + rtoken );
         $rootScope.refreshToken=rtoken;
       console.log('token' + token)
   });
      FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
            if(data.wasTapped){
  
        alert((data) );
       }
      else{
               
     alert((data) );
     }
    },function(msg){
    console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
   },
    function(err){
   console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
     })

   if (window.cordova && window.Keyboard) {
    window.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
         if (window.StatusBar) {
         StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
     });
     })
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the error you're getting.

Comment: @JM-AGMS I am not getting any error. App is running properly .  i tried to access token using alert but its showing nothing .

Comment: @AshishChaurasiya Did u solve it? I am also facing the same issue. I am using Ionic V1, angular js.

Comment: I solved using this link https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging